# Tiny cme html editor with angular js

Tags: css, angularjs, tinymce

I am using TinyCME html editor with the [angular directive](https://www.tinymce.com/docs/integrations/angularjs/)
and I render the output of the editor -which is data-bidden to property "description" in the scope- into a div using ng-html-bind.

```
<div ng-bind-html="description" ></div>
```

everything is working fine but I didn't get in the div what I see in the editor 
especially when it comes to styling like the background color and text color
here is what I get in the editor
[image]

and here is what I get in the div

[image]

it sounds like all the styles applied in the editor will eventually be overwritten by the styles in the div context

I don't have any experience in CSS so please excuse my lack of knowledge

What I really want to do is to render the editor output in a div in a way exactly the way it looks in the editor any help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved the problem the issue comes from that the ng-bind-html strips out all the styling info comes from the editor that's why there is no styling info

to solve the problem we should use angularjs service $sec which tells the ng-bind-html not to strip out anything from the html string

so to use it in the angular expression we should make it as a filter

```
app.filter('trustAsHtml', ["$sce", function ($sce) { return $sce.trustAsHtml; } ] );
```

then you can use this filter in the binding expression like the following:

```
<div ng-bind-html="currentModel.description | trustAsHtml" ></div>
```